# Git: Keep system generated/modifed files unaffected my commits

Tags: git

I am working on C# dot net project where recenly introduced git.

While building It will generated many dll files and modifies many tracked js files.

These files anyway I don't need to commit and push.
But these files preventing me to pull latest from a branch, switching to different branch etc.
I would like to get a simple solution for this problem so that

1. It should allow me to switch branch by keeping these files as it is.
2. While pulling new changes if any changes are to be applied to these js files from remote It should be applied on but still it should allow me to switch branch and pull new changes.
3. I should be able commit other files that I changed easily

Please suggest the steps for this in git commands.

(I made those generated and system modified files as untracked but while pulling new changes it is not going because there are changes to be applied on files that I made untracked)

Comment: It sounds like you need to [ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) the build files. A good place to start is to ignore everything in the bin and obj folder.

Comment: tried `.gitignore`?

Comment: Actually, it sounds to me that some of these files are already part of your repository, in which case simply adding them to `.gitignore` won't have any effect.  First, you might have to `git rm --cached` those files.  But you should consider why these files were versioned in the first place, before you remove them.

Answer (score 0):

For files you want to not put in source control, use the `.gitignore` file.  Since the files are already in the repo, you will need to take steps to remove them - at least by adding commits to each branch to remove them (see `git rm --cached`), or possibly by editing history (e.g. with `git filter-branch`).

You can search here for each of those topic and find many answers explaining them.  Also you can refer to the git docs, such as

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for `.gitignore`
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm for `git rm --cached`
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch for `git filter-branch`

For files where you want to be able to receive changes from the remote, but also don't want to be blocked from changing branches... that can't be done in any remotely safe way.  Either a file is under source control, changes are shared, and all of the rules about managing uncommitted changes apply; or it is not under source control and is managed independently in each clone.

In the simplest case, you would have 3 distinct types of file:  Files that are generated by the build process, which you never edit and which are not stored in source control; files from 3rd-party sources such as dependencies, which you also do not edit or put in source control, but which are pulled in by dependency management software during the build; and files you edit, which are never modified by automated means and are the only thing in source control, so you always want to share the changes to these files and there's never an automatic change that would block you from a pull or branch-switch.

If your process requires you to have files that do not fit these categories, then the first thing I'd do is review your process - because source control issues are just the first (and mildest) problems that come from having a single file that takes changes from 2 or more of those categories.

If you must have the build process modify files that either are locally authored and source controlled, or are 3rd-party files pulled in with a dependency, then the build process should copy the file and operate on the copy.  The modified copy should be `.gitignore`d and the original should be left alone by the build process.

If you must have files that mix locally-authored changes into 3rd-party files, then you should set up a repo for "your version" of the dependency that introduces such files (a fork if they're also using git for source control), with a vendor branch so that you are able to incorporate future changes that they make to their files if you need to.  Again this is a topic you can search on and find many existing answers about.